# Function to add date +3 working days excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a function with 2 parameters, datenow and '3' for adding date + 3 working days.

I have successfully adding date+3 working day for weekend, but for holiday the result is not what I expected, for the holiday I have a table called lkp_holiday
the idea is to get the current date and check the date on lkp_holiday and if there is same date then add for addDate

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DATEADDEXCLUDEWD](@addDate AS DATE, @numDays AS INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DateHoliday DATETIME

  WHILE @numDays > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)
      --For weekend
    IF DATENAME(DW, @addDate) = 'saturday' SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)
    IF DATENAME(DW, @addDate) = 'sunday' SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)
      --For Holiday
      IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT hol_date  FROM [Vacation].[dbo].[Lkp_Holiday] WHERE hol_date > GETDATE())
      BEGIN
          DECLARE M_CURSOR CURSOR
          FOR SELECT DISTINCT hol_date  FROM [Vacation].[dbo].[Lkp_Holiday] WHERE hol_date > GETDATE()

          OPEN M_CURSOR
          FETCH NEXT FROM M_CURSOR INTO @DateHoliday

          WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
          BEGIN
              SET @addDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @addDate)

              FETCH NEXT FROM M_CURSOR INTO @DateHoliday
          END
          CLOSE M_CURSOR
          DEALLOCATE M_CURSOR
      END                                         

    SET @numDays = @numDays - 1
  END

  RETURN CAST(@addDate AS DATETIME)
END
```

For example today is 2019-05-17, add 3 days, the output 2019-05-22 =>> it's true, because it including weekend

I have run the function and inside the lkp_holiday table I have one date holiday, let say 2019-05-23

What I expect is 2019-05-24, but the result from this function is 2019-05-25

Comment: You could do something like storing the initial date, the end date, and then checking to see if any holiday date exists in between the start/end date.. I feel like the performance on that would be better than a cursor, but I haven't tried it out to be sure.

Comment: for such case, it is best if you have your own calendar table. It makes things much easier. You will be able to handle weekend, public holiday etc at ease

Comment: if you are saying 23rd as holiday, still the output you showed 22nd is intact right ? it is a working day. how come you expect it as 25th ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is far from the best way to solve this issue. However going with getting your code working there are the following issues, corrected in the code that follows:

1. You needed to check that the holiday date was the date being processed by the loop, otherwise you added it on every time you ran through the loop.
2. To do that you needed your `@DateHoliday` variable to be of type date not datetime.
3. To ensure that the weekend skip code works you need to apply it *before* you add a day
4. Also the output from "2019-05-17" with a holiday on "2019-05-23" is still "2019-05-22" but the output from "2019-05-18" is now "2019-05-24" i.e. its then added another day to account for the holiday day.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DATEADDEXCLUDEWD]
    (
      @addDate AS DATE
      , @numDays AS INT
    )
    RETURNS DATETIME
    AS
    BEGIN
      -- Needs to be a date type to allow for a date to date compare in the holiday section
      DECLARE @DateHoliday DATE

      WHILE @numDays > 0
      BEGIN
          --For weekend

        -- Add these before the regular add date, as otherwise we've already moved the date forward 1 day
        IF DATENAME(DW, @addDate) = 'saturday' SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)
        IF DATENAME(DW, @addDate) = 'sunday' SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)

        SET @addDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @addDate)

          --For Holiday
          IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT hol_date FROM [Vacation].[dbo].[Lkp_Holiday] WHERE hol_date > GETDATE())
          BEGIN
              DECLARE M_CURSOR CURSOR
              FOR SELECT DISTINCT hol_date FROM [Vacation].[dbo].[Lkp_Holiday] WHERE hol_date > GETDATE()

              OPEN M_CURSOR
              FETCH NEXT FROM M_CURSOR INTO @DateHoliday

              WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
              BEGIN
            -- Only add the day if we've on the holiday day
            if @DateHoliday = @addDate begin
                  SET @addDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @addDate)
            end

                  FETCH NEXT FROM M_CURSOR INTO @DateHoliday
              END
              CLOSE M_CURSOR
              DEALLOCATE M_CURSOR
          END                                     

        SET @numDays = @numDays - 1
      END

      RETURN CAST(@addDate AS DATETIME)
    END
```